# Find point in right triangle with given one vector and one point

Tags: graphics, geometry, trigonometry

I am developing a game where the user move a car with his finger. The car is represented as vector (one point and angle of rotation in the screen). When the user start to dragging the car he generate a new point P. I am trying to smooth the moving of the car so it won't change its angle if the point is somewhere +/- 10px which is the margin of the car (The car is represented as rectangular). Here is an image for better explaining:
[image]

How to find the point M(x,y)?

(Please note, the angle α is the rotation of the car, not the angle of point O and P)

Comment: To clarify things a bit: Angle (a) is the angle MOP? Do you know the coordinates of P? Do you know length OM? Do you know the length OP?

Comment: Angle (a) is rotation of the red rectangular not MOP, but that angle is easy to find. P is the touched point on the screen (it is known). So the length OP is again easy to find. The distance OP however is not know but we can find it: OM = OP * cos(a). I hope it is more clear now. Thanks.

Comment: M is different from P. The current solution is just like that (M=P) and the car is rotating even on small distance from the touch point, which is quite boring. I want to improve the moving of the car with this.

Comment: OM = OP * cos(a) is only true if the angle (a) is the angle MOP to the best of my knowledge. You are saying that angle (a) is NOT the angle MOP!

Comment: Yes, you are right, I just try to explain that OM is easy to find by cos of the angle between OP and OM.

Comment: Not quite trivial...I suggest posting in http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

not sure if I get it right but:

1. **you want to eliminate small angle differences to avoid oscillations**

   so truncate to some angles for that

   ```cpp
    const double acc=5.0*M_PI/180.0; // truncate to 5 deg angle steps
    double a=atan2(P.y-O.y,P.x-O.x); // P direction [rad]
    a=round(a/acc)*acc;                // truncate
    M.x=x0+delta*cos(a);
    M.y=y0+delta*sin(a);
   ```

   where `delta` is `speed*time` to get the `M` as new car position
2. **you want to make the car more realistic**

   then use angle integration instead:

   ```cpp
    double alpha=0.0; // car direction [rad]
    double omega=0.0; // car rotation speed [rad/s]
    double epsilon=0.0; // car rotation acceleration [rad/s^2]
    // in timer (update) with interval dt [s]
    double a=atan2(P.y-O.y,P.x-O.x); // P direction [rad]
    a-=alpha; // get the difference and handle overflows
    while (a<-M_PI) a+=2.0*M_PI;
    while (a>+M_PI) a-=2.0*M_PI;
    epsilon=(some_rotation_speed_constant)*a/M_PI;
    omega+=epsilon*dt;
    alpha+=omega*dt;
    M.x=x0+delta*cos(alpha);
    M.y=y0+delta*sin(alpha);
   ```

   you should use integration also for position. Also you can add some regulator for the turning wheel **P,PI** or **PID** if you do not want to do it manually
3. **you want just `M` and know `P,O`,and car direction angle `a`**

   then exploit dot product

   ```cpp
    D.x=cos(a);
    D.y=sin(a);
    M=O+(D*dot(P-O,D));
    if (|M-P|<10px) ignore_turning;
   ```

   just in case `dot(A,B)=(A.x*B.x)+(A.y*B.y);`

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort to write this answer. I have two questions: 1. the line M=O+(D*dot(P-O,D)); the P-O is vector right? (P.x-O.x, P.y-O.y), and 2. I think the plus sign in the dot equation should be multiply instead in (A.y+B.y)

Comment: @Ivica yes it is vector and yes it is a typo (have edited it already) ps the dot product gives you the perpendicular projection of one vector to the other one size as scalar multiply of the other vector ...

Answer (score 0):

**OM** is perpendicular to **PM** and in the direction defined by `a` (alpha), i.e. **OM**`= m.(cos a, sin a)`.

Let us cancel the dot product:

`m.(cos a, sin a).(x1 - m.cos a, y1 - m.sin a) = 0 = m.(x1.cos a + y1.sin a - m)`,

giving `m = x1.cos a + y1.sin a`.

**OM**`= (x1.cos a + y1.sin a).(cos a, sin a)`.

Answer (score -1):

Given O(x0, y0), alpha and P(x1, y1):

```
M.x = 1/2 ( (y0 - y1) / tan(alpha) + x0 + x1 )
M.y = 1/2 ( (x0 - x1) * tan(alpha) + y0 + y1 )
```

You may need to tweak signs to match your coordinate system