# How can an angle to rotate be determined for a moving object taking into account the object’s velocit?

Tags: math, game-physics, game-development

In 2d space, I have a boat that travels to the position of user input via screen touches. The question is that while traveling toward the position of one touch (with varying velocity and speed), when a second touch occurs how can I determine the angle the boat should rotate to make the turn?

The angle it rotates to is currently found using the atan2 method passing in the difference between the coordinates like usual; the touch position’s y minus the boat’s position y, same for x. The duration the rotation should take to occur is found by dividing the distance between the 2 points by the boat’s speed.

I have access to the boat’s constantly updated velocity, max acceleration, speed, max speed, and other physical properties, but I’m not sure how to calculate for the change in directions from one point to the other when the boat is in motion. When the velocity is very low the turn occurs perfectly, but when the boat is moving fast in one direction and then turns to change towards the new direction it rotates inaccurately, and the resulting rotation is a bit less rotated than it needs to be to face the direction of the new point it is headed to.

Comment: Please consider [math.se] or [gamedev.se] for this.

Comment: Do you want the boat to draw a circumference or just a line to new target? "*The duration of the rotation*" is confusing me.

Comment: I want the boat to change directions with convincing rotational accuracy. So it's heading in one direction with increasing forward velocity and suddenly receives a new coordinate and it decelerates while it begins turning to head in the direction of the new coordinate. It has an effect almost like turning around on a jetski but the problem is that after turning around it doesn't exactly point at the center of the coordinate it is headed towards.

Comment: If heading is wrong because it was calculated before some moving, then you have to recalculate direction angle after moving. If you want to rotate like real boat - change angle at every time period until needed direction is reached (apply angular/rotational velocity)

Comment: You simply add PID (or just P or PI) regulator to drive your angle towards wanted heading along with Newton D'Alembert integration to simulate your movement... see almost duplicate [driving/turning 2D car](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27898784/2521214)